# How to identify part of the localStorage key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have following types of keys in my localStorage,

```
Key: Designer-96, Value: true
Key: Designer-76, Value: true
```

On Page_Load() I want to identify if localStorage contains any keys that start with `Designer` word, if that's the case then I want to execute certain logic.

Is it possible to iterate through the keys of localStorage in JavaScript and find part of the matching key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all keys of `localStorge` using

```
Object.keys(localStorage)
```

and you can then use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check for the existence of a key starts with `Designer`

```
const ls = localStorage;

ls.setItem("Designer-96", true);
ls.setItem("Designer-76", true);

const keys = Object.keys(ls);
if (keys.some((k) => k.startsWith("Designer"))) console.log("Key is present");
else console.log("Key is not present");
```